# Understand C++ const functions

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and im trying to write a simple c++ wrappers to integrate with this third party c++ library; which comes with bad documentation.

function to integrate with (this is all the documentation that came with this function):

```
 virtual ImageCoord Raster::groundToImage(const XyzCoord & groundPt, 
              double desiredPrecision=0.001, 
              double* achievedPrecision=null) const
```

Text about function: This method converts the given groundPt (x,y,z in meters) to a returned image coordinate (line, sample in full image space pixels).

there is also some class documentation

```
Raster Class Ref
inherits from GeoModel
Public member functions:

virtual ImageCoord  groundToImage (const XyzCoord &groundPt, double desiredPrecision=0.001, double *achievedPrecision=NULL) const =0
```

in my code i have:

```
   //this is implemented correctly 
    const XyzCoord xyz(284971.17549099098, -126866.36533847413, 6350003.627515804)
    double desiredPrecision = 0.000001;
    double achievedPrecision = 0.0;

    // not sure if this is what the documentation meant by "image coordinate" but it comes with the library
    // ImageCoord(double line, double point)
    ImageCoord imagePoints;

    // the part im confused about, what is the proper way to invoke the above function, the below line was me trying out how to call the method 
    const Raster::groundToImage(&xyz, imagePoints);
```

Sorry for my ignorance in c++ but I've been baffled. I have lot of programing experience (8 plus years, just none with c++ so i understand programing terms, concepts and design patterns).
Im also trying to understand in the function defination what does this mean

> const XyzCoord & groundPt

I was able to compile with

```
XyzCoord xyz(204971.17549099098, -106866.36533847413, 6350003.627515804);
Raster* service;
ImageCoord imagePoints = service->groundToImage(xyz); //segmentation error occurs on this line
```

but i then get a runtime error "Segmentation fault"

Comment: The function you posted cannot compile, you cannot have a parameter with a default value followed by a parameter without one

Comment: The function should be invoked as `object.groundToImage(xyz, desiredPrecision, achievedPrecision);` However, it should be a member function in some class. It also lacks the return value in the signature. All this fundamental information is missing in the question. Without it it is hard to come up with an answer

Comment: It's a function, call it with the required number of parameters, of the required type. There's no mystery here. Now your code has several WTF, why `const`, why `csm::RasterGM::`, why are the types all wrong? It's hard to suggest what the fix is, because I can't really make sense of what you have written,

Comment: Q: did you forget to copy/paste the return value of groundToImage()?  Q: is it a standalone function, or a class method?  Q: Did you inherit this code from "someplace else", and you're trying to figure out why THEY specified "const"?  Or did you add "const" yourself?

Comment: @paulsm4 The final const in the declaration suggests it's a non-static method.

Comment: @john - I SURMISED that was probably the case.  I was just trying to get the OP to think a bit harder, and supply some missing info.  Ideally,he'll a) answer all my questions, b) maybe even add a few details he didn't orginally mention in the question itself.

Comment: Based on the latest edit `imagePoints = groundToImage(xyz, desiredPrecision, &achievedPrecision);` is closer to correct (but still might not be fully correct).

Comment: Another guess would be `imagePoints = ecef.groundToImage(xyz, desiredPrecision, &achievedPrecision);` But this is guesswork as important information is still missing from the question, like what is `ecef`, and what class is `groundToImage` in. And from what class (if any) is the call being made from.

Comment: the above definition of groundToImage, is all the information i have on the function and now mirrors the pdf doc i have on it. The last line of code '''const Raster::groundToImage(&ecef, imagePoints);'''  was me trying to figure out how to call the method. Im also trying to find a good crash course on c++

Comment: Presumably you know the name of the class this method is part of? Do you have a variable that class (ecef maybe)?

Comment: It means that the function expects the first parameter to be an object of type `XyzCoord` (or a reference to the same). And that object will not be modified by the function (that's what the const part means).

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of `const`. When you see const it's a promise that something will not be modified, it's not a requirement on you to supply a const object. It's perfectly OK to supply a non-const object to a const parameter. (But not the other way around).

Comment: Just as a word of advice, C++ is not the kind of language in which you can write useful code just by noodling around until it works. If you need to write C++ code you are going to have to spend some time learning C++.

Answer (score 3):

This is a non-static member function of a class named `Raster`.

You are supposed to invoke it via member access `obj.groundToImage(/*args*/)` where `obj` is an object of the class type to which the function belongs or a class type derived from that class.

Or, if the call happens inside another non-static member function of the same class or a derived class, it could just be `groundToImage(/*args*/)` which will call the function implicitly on the current object.

With `virtual` it may also be possible to invoke the function on an object of a base class of `Raster`, depending on where the virtual function has been declared first in the class hierarchy.

There are certain more specialized situations where a qualified call replacing `groundToImage` with `Raster::groundToImage` in either of the above could also be the intended behavior.

The `const` qualification of the function is irrelevant. It just means that the function can be called whether `obj` is `const`-qualified or not. Similarly the `const`-qualification on the function parameter is irrelevant. It just means that you can pass either a `const`- or non-`const`-qualified first argument. You don't have to make `xyz` const to be able to pass it. Only the other way around, passing a `const`-qualified expression to a non-`const` reference parameter is a problem. `const` is intended to signal that the function will not modify the argument and therefore doesn't care whether or not it is `const`-qualified.

`const` only makes sense when used in a declaration or type. Something like

```
const Raster::groundToImage(&ecef, imagePoints)
```

as a supposed function call doesn't make syntactical sense.

The function also expects up to three arguments of the specified types and *returns* a `ImageCoord`. You are not supposed to pass one as an argument. It is what the function returns.

The arguments should probably be `xyz`, `desiredPrecision` and `&achievedPrecision` given that you already declared them with the correct types.

It probably wants the last one as pointer because it is an out-parameter.

What the object on which the member function is called on is supposed to be is unclear from what you have shown. We don't know what `ecef` is though...

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR:

```
ImageCoord imagePoint = someRasterObject.groundToImage(
    xyz,
    desiredPrecision,
    &achivedPrecision
);
```

Or

```
ImageCoord imagePoint = somePointerToRasterObject->groundToImage(
    xyz,
    desiredPrecision,
    &achivedPrecision
);
```

---

From the signature given:

```
virtual                                 // A derived class's implementation of 
                                        //   this function can be called via a
                                        //   pointer or reference to a parent
                                        //   class object
ImageCoord                              // This function returns an ImageCoord
                                        //   object
Raster::                                // This is a member of the Raster class
groundToImage(                          // This function is named groundToImage
     const XyzCoord & groundPt,         // The first argument to this function is a
                                        //   reference to a constant XyzCoord
                                        //   object
     double desiredPrecision=0.001,     // The second argument is a double with a
                                        //   default value of 0.001 if not provided
     double* achievedPrecision=null     // The third argument is a pointer to a
                                        //   double with a default value of null if
                                        //   not provided
)
const                                   // This function can be called on a
                                        //   constant Raster object
```

That means you need 2-4 things to call this function:

1. A (possibly `const`-qualified) `Raster` object to call the function on
2. An `XyzCoord` object to pass as the first parameter
3. (Optional) A `double` to pass as the second parameter
4. (Optional) A pointer to a `double` to pass as the third parameter

While nothing in your question explicitly states it, I would assume the function uses the 3rd parameter as an output.  I would assume it writes the actually achieved precision to the `double` pointed to by the pointer you pass it, so you'll probably want to just pass it the address of a local `double` variable.

Comment: this lead me in the right direction and i can compile but. get runtime error of segmentation fault (updated code)

Comment: @ParkerDell You need an actual `Raster` object (or an object of a class derived from it) for that pointer to point to.  Currently it points to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Each non-static method in a class is called on behalf of some object of that class (or some derived class), and the object is accessible within a method by an implicitly defined `this` pointer.

The `const` qualifier appended after the parameters' list of the method applies to that `this` value. In other words, it declares `this` of a type `classname const*` instead of `classname*`.

As a result the compiler will reject any attempts to modify the `*this` object from within the `const`-qualified method, so the method can be safely used on non-modifiable objects.

For example, the `length()` method of the `std::string` class is declared as

```
 size_t length() const;
```

so when you use it like, say:

```
std:string s;
....
size_t len = s.length();
```

you can be sure the `s` variable will not be modified during calculation of `len` value.